Webpack - Difference between putting loader and options in the "use" property vs outside
What is the difference between a module rule of the form:
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: { rootMode: 'root', cacheDirectory: true }
}

and
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: [{
        loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
        options: { rootMode: 'root', cacheDirectory: true }
    }]
}

The first one has the loader and its options on the same level as the module rule. The second one has the loader and its options in the use property.
Is there a difference between them? Are they interchangeable? Is one preferred over the other?
Note: We are on Webpack 5

I think when you take the use approach you can have an array of (chained) loaders with options to each loader and where you can order the different loaders while without you can have only one loader with it's options. At least the documentation looks like that to me: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration

in your concrete use case is no difference.
If you have only one loader in the rule, then you can write without use:
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: { rootMode: 'root', cacheDirectory: true }
}

But for some rules are needed two or more loaders, then in the use property can be defined many loaders, e.g.:
{
  test: /\.(s?css|sass)$/,
  use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},

